# SQL Subquery with JOIN

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I'm trying to learn Subquerys.
I have troubles with this:

**The two tables:**

```
CREATE TABLE DEPT
(DEPTNO NUMBER(2) CONSTRAINT DEPT_PRIMARY_KEY PRIMARY KEY,
LOC varchar2(3));

CREATE TABLE EMP
(ENAME varchar2(10),
JOB varchar2(9),
DEPTNO NUMBER(2) NOT NULL
CONSTRAINT EMP_FOREIGN_KEY REFERENCES DEPT (DEPTNO));
```

I want to get the name (emp.ename) and the job (emp.job) but only where the job also exists in 'CHICAGO'.

**This is what I have done:**

```
SELECT emp1.ename, emp1.job
FROM emp emp1
WHERE emp1.job EXISTS (SELECT emp2.job
                      FROM emp emp2
                      FULL JOIN dept ON (emp2.deptno = dept.deptno)
                      WHERE dept.loc = 'CHICAGO');
```

I always get the "invalid relational operator" error in the line 3.

**Example of the outcome:**

```
ENAME | JOB  | LOC 
JONES | SALE | CHICAGO 
FORD  | SALE | NEW YORK  //He doesn't sit in CHICAGO but the job also exists in Chicago
```

Comment: I guess my second query would help you get the desired output.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To simplify your query, you can use:

```
select emp1.ename, emp1.job 
from EMP emp1 
where emp1.deptno in (SELECT DEPT.DEPTNO from DEPT where DEPT.loc = 'CHICAGO');
```

---

To select name and job from emp1 where emp1's job is same as emp2's job with location Chicago:

```
SELECT emp1.ename, emp1.job
FROM emp emp1
WHERE emp1.job IN (SELECT emp2.job
                      FROM emp emp2
                      FULL JOIN dept ON (emp2.deptno = dept.deptno)
                      WHERE dept.loc = 'CHICAGO');
```

---

To select name and job from emp1 if there exists atleast one record with location in chicago.

```
  SELECT emp1.ename, emp1.job
    FROM emp emp1
    WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT emp2.job
                   FROM emp emp2
                   FULL JOIN dept ON (emp2.deptno = dept.deptno)
                   WHERE dept.loc = 'CHICAGO');
```

---

In your case, i assume that the first and second query would be more appropriate.

Comment: The first query and the second are the same, you should add a where clause where the ename from emp2 is different from the ename of emp1, then they are different and give you some different results.

Comment: @Bajellor: I guess my second query would help you get the desired output

Answer (score 1):

The `exists` operator is applied on a subquery, not a column:

```
SELECT emp1.ename, emp1.job
FROM emp emp1
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT emp2.job
               FROM emp emp2
               FULL JOIN dept ON (emp2.deptno = dept.deptno)
               WHERE dept.loc = 'CHICAGO');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this sub Query this will use sub query.

```
select ENAME,JOB from EMP where DEPTNO in (SELECT DEPTNO from DEPT where loc = 'CHICAGO');
```

Comment: Doesn't work like this I need where the job also exists in chicago not where the worker works in chicago

Comment: Your requirement is not very clear to me will u please explain it in little deep and give some sample data output so that i can help u.. Thanku.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
SELECT emp1.ename, emp1.job
FROM emp emp1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT NULL
              FROM emp emp2
              FULL JOIN dept ON (emp2.deptno = dept.deptno)
              WHERE dept.loc = 'CHICAGO'
              AND emp1.job=emp2.job);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing IN-Subqueries and Correlated Subqueries (and do an unnecessary FULL join):

```
SELECT emp1.ename, emp1.job
FROM emp emp1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT *
                      FROM emp emp2
                      JOIN dept ON (emp2.deptno = dept.deptno)
                      WHERE dept.loc = 'CHICAGO'
                      AND emp1.kob = emp2.job);

SELECT emp1.ename, emp1.job
FROM emp emp1
WHERE emp1.job IN (SELECT emp2.job
                      FROM emp emp2
                      JOIN dept ON (emp2.deptno = dept.deptno)
                      WHERE dept.loc = 'CHICAGO');
```